# 1970’s ABS OD Pipe Size is Larger

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent, abs, pipe-fitting

We have a 1974 condo with some lateral 2” ABS schedule 40 pipe. Strange, but current fittings with hubs do not fit the old pipe. It’s as if the older pipe is just “slightly” larger than the current 2.375 OD that ABS should be.

When I say slightly, I mean more than what can be cleaned or sanded away.

Was pipe sizing different 50 years ago or does ABS pipe swell or expand?

I’m trying to figure out a way to avoid rubber couplings.

The use case is below grade drain pipe.

Comment: what is slightly ???, get a tool and measure it, keep in mind if you thin it, the wall thickness might become a problem for stability

Comment: Do you have a heat gun ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using heat gun on the new fittings

gently warm them up,

GENTLY

they will expand, maybe enough to fit.

In this example, this was done with heat

[image: abs]